# CLEAR SCREEN - Oracle SQL Developer shortcut?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

With the aim of reducing mouse activity I was wondering if there was such a command shortcut (eg `cls` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) to provide the `SQL * Plus (?) "CLEAR SCREEN"` command functionality found by clicking the rubber-on-end- of-pencil icon in `Oracle SQL Developer` to clear the lower "`Results`" sub-tab (*... incorrect terminology I'm sure*).

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+D, but you have to put focus on the script output panel first...which you can do via the KB.

Run script.

Alt+PgDn     -  puts you in Script Output panel.
Ctrl+Shift+D -  clears panel.
Alt+PgUp     -  puts you back in editor panel.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve012.htm#SQPUG033

Answer (score 69):

To clear the SQL window you can use:

```
clear screen;
```

which can also be shortened to

```
cl scr;
```

Comment: Yes this doesn't answer the question, but it's the only place I've found that explains how to clear the SQL developer screen from inside a script. +1

Comment: Can you create a function which clears the screen? So instead of typing clear screen, you could just say for example clear.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using sqlplus in a shell, like bash you can run the shell's clear command from sqlplus:

```
SQL> host clear
```

you can abbreviate of course:

```
SQL> ho clear
```

Answer (score 7):

SQL>Clear Screen (It is used the Clear The Screen FUlly in SQL Plus Window)

Answer (score 7):

Use `cl scr` on the Sql*  command line tool to clear all the matter on the screen.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following command to clear screen in sqlplus.

```
SQL > clear scr
```

Answer (score 4):

CTRL+D? http://www.scribd.com/doc/7580088/SQL-Developer-Hot-Keys

If that doesn't work, you might be able to set up an Accelerator: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b31695/intro.htm#sthref208

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl+Shift+D, but you have to put focus on the script output panel first...which you can do via the KB.

Run script.

```
Alt+PgDn     -  puts you in Script Output panel.
Ctrl+Shift+D -  clears panel.
Alt+PgUp     -  puts you back in editor panel.
```

Answer (score -2):

In the Oracle SQL-plus:

```
shift+del
```

Comment: wrong command for use