# I have install oracle 11g in window 7 of my pc.

Tags: oracle11g

when I work on SQL PLUS it does not work clear screen command and it shows as sp2-1530:command did not succeed. how to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you think you could rephrase it a bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CLEAR SCREEN - Oracle SQL Developer shortcut?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109067/clear-screen-oracle-sql-developer-shortcut) (there are answers for SQL Plus as well)